# pool of applicant

Tags: meaning

> **University president:** Our pool of applicants has been shrinking over
>   the past few years.

I have two candidates for the meaning of pool. What does pool mean in this sentence?

1. Group of contestants who compete against each other
2. a group of people available for work when required or considered as a resource

Comment: Those are both good candidates, so #whynotboth -- why would you assume only one meaning could apply in some fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-W.com has the following as one of the definitions of [(3) pool, n.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pool)

> 4. : a readily available supply: such as
>
>    - a: the whole quantity of a particular material present in the body and available for function or the satisfying of metabolic demands
>    - b : a body product (such as blood) collected from many donors and stored for later use
>    - c : a group of people available for some purpose * a shrinking *pool* of applicants * typing pool

The "pool of applicants" are the group of people applying.  What they are applying for is anyone's guess (admission to the university, a program within the university, who gets to feed the university's mascot).  So, without further context it would be hard to support either of your suggested candidates.